# How to doatomic CAS operation on two adjacent bits of a byte?

Tags: gcc, c++11, atomic, bitmask, compare-and-swap

Say there is:

```
unsigned char byte = someValue;
```

What I need, is to perform an atomic CAS (compare and swap) operation on some two adjacent bits in `byte`, say the fourth and the fifth.

For sure, there is no way to address something shorter than a byte, but there is a CAS function for a byte, so the following:

```
unsigned char expected = expectedValue;
unsigned char desired  =  desiredValue;
// atomic CAS operation for byte
__atomic_compare_exchange_n( &byte, &expected, desired, 0, std::memory_order_seq_cst, std::memory_order_seq_cst );
```

will atomically compare `byte` with `expected`, if those are EQUAL, will assign `desired` to `byte` and return `true`, otherwise (i.e. if `byte` is NOT EQUAL to `expected`), it will assign `byte` to `expected` and return `false`.

Thus, if it were a CAS operation for byte, where the comparison is done not by just checking the EQUALITY, but doing some bitwise operation, like  bitwise-and or bitwise-or, then it would be possible to do CAS for bits.

So the question turns to be if there is a CAS operation for bytes which, when comparing, looks not for the equality, but to some bitwise operation like bitwise-and or bitwise-or?

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701401/atomic-compare-exchange-with-greater-than-instead-of-equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [is there] a CAS operation for bytes which, when comparing, looks not for the equality, but to some bitwise operation like bitwise-and or bitwise-or?

In C++, the only Compare And Swap operation checks for equality. So the answer is a flat **no**.

Additionally, I don't know a single CPU that behaves otherwise (though there *might* be in the microprocessor / DSP categories, who knows, some can do really weird, specialized things).

Comment: But maybe there are some third party libraries which have such CAS operations, or maybe there are some Assembler routines which do it, and can be called from the C++ code?

Comment: @Vahagn This is why I mentioned CPUs. All mainstream CPUs either have a CAS operation, or Load/Store semantics. Either way, that means comparing for equality.